# How do I use LINQ in this scenario?

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to LINQ.

I have a SortedDictionary

```
SortedDictionary<int, int> book = new SortedDictionary<int, int>();
```

and the pair are

(5,10),(7,20),(8,30),(9,15),(10,60)

Is there any LINQ statement that can allow me to selected the lowest key whose value is more than 25? For this example, it is the key is 8

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote in this question? It seems fine on my end

Comment: Why downvote? It doesn't show research effort. Nothing has been tried. No code except a useless `new` statement.

Comment: @Thomas Sorry I have learnt my mistake.

Comment: @ThomasW. A downvote should be use to encourage to the improve the question not just to free up some anger.. No comments were left on the question. A downvote should be come along with a comment

Comment: @Dalorzo: Well, I did leave a comment, didn't I? If you ask for the second downvote, I don't know who it was...

Comment: If you want to learn LINQ and don't know the LINQ statement, just implement how you would do in normal code. Buy Resharper or any other tool of your choice which has the feature, and it will suggest a LINQ statement whenever possible. You can also convert LINQ back to code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it's a sorted dictionary (and therefore the first key matching the criteria is always the lowest key matching the criteria), you can just do:

```
var result = book.First(o => o.Value > 25).Key;
```

Comment: @user3398315 If you end up using this solution, please also accept the answer.

Comment: Note that `First()` will throw an exception if no such value exists.

Answer (score 1):

```
book.Where(i => i.Item > 25).Min(i => i.Key)
```

Comment: This is fairly inefficient since `Where` and `Min` cannot take advantage of the fact the keys are sorted so it will search the entire collection.